# can't show abline on plots in a loop

Tags: r, loops, plot, horizontal-line

I have an xts with 5 columns of price data. I want to plot each column of data as a line graph and add a horizontal line unique to each column. My code is:

```r
pColours <- sequential_hcl(5, palette = "Viridis")

target = c(1,3,5,7,9)

for (i in 1:5) {

  mydata <- xts[ ,i]

  plot(mydata, col = pColours[i], main = "blah blah", ylim = (0,8), 
       major.ticks = "auto", minor.ticks = NULL))

  abline(h = target[i], col = "red")
}
```

I get error in int_abline .. plot.new has not been called yet. I understand plot is built in layers and have tried so many ways to get the abline on each chart. I just can't get the abline to plot on the line graph. Help!

Comment: What is `xts`? It sounds like it's a special-class object (that might not be base-graphics). (It might be best to include a sample of your data so that we can try to reproduce your error.)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. After fixing some minor issues and removing the `major.ticks` and `minor.ticks` I got a plot.

Comment: xts is a time series object in R. In my case, it contains rolling standard deviations for 5 stocks.

Answer (score 0):

The abline should be printed to every plot correctly:

- `ylim` should be a vector `c(0,8)`... missing `c`,
- remove `major.ticks` and `minor.ticks`,
- correct pairs of parentheses in your code.

This simple example (based on yours) works properly:

```
target = c(1,3,5,7)
for (i in 1:4) {
    mydata <- target
    plot(mydata, main = "blah blah", ylim = c(0,8))
    abline(h = target[i], col = "red")
}
```

Although this is a bit strange example, it works and creates a number of plots with abline.

[image: first example]

If you want more lines in one plot, you can just move the loop:

```
target = c(1,3,5,7)
mydata <- target
plot(mydata, main = "blah blah", ylim = c(0,8))
for (i in 1:4) {
    abline(h = target[i], col = "red")
}
```

[image: second example]

Comment: Thank you. Ive solved the problem by adding the targets to the xts object (xts$target1 <- 1.2) and then used lines(xts[ ,"target1], col = "red') to plot the line. Abline() is a strange beast!